# Export HTML table and save to .json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have an HTML table that reads and loads a JSON file through an ajax call which then allows the user to make changes to that data.

The program was entirely done in HTML and JavaScript/jQuery.

It's pretty much finished and I already have the output with the changes formatted to JSON but I still need to find a way to export that output and either save it to a file (which is something you apparently can't do using JavaScript -security reasons?) or update the old one.

So my question is, what would be the simplest way to have this done?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can "create" a file by creating an `<a>` with a `data URI` that triggers a download.

```js
function download(filename, text) {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/json;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```

```css
form * {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="download(this['name'].value, this['text'].value)">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="data.json">
  <textarea name="text">{
  "a": "b",
  "arr": [
    {
      "c": "d"
    },
    {
      "d": "e"
    }
  ]
}</textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Download">
</form>
```

Found this snippet some time ago and had it saved since then.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to mess with the server, you can just display the data to the user as text in some element and maybe also add a button for quick copy. Then the user can save it to a file if he wants.

If automatic saving to a file is necessity, then you have to:

- Send the data back to the server

How to:

```
// the code supposes that you have a variable `data` containing the JSON
var request = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    body = new FormData();
body.append('user_data', data);
// The url here points to a url with path according to the desired functionality on the server
request.open("POST", "http://yourwebsite/jsonHandle", true); 
request.send(body);
```

In case you can not count on `FormData()` in the browser you are using, you can do this:

```
request.send("user_data=" + data);
```

In this case we are using a post request in order to keep the json data inside the body of the request and not reveal it inside the url. If you do not care about it - use a get request.

Afterwards you have 2 options:

1. Send the resulting file as response
2. Save the file to the server and redirect the user to the path (if the path is not constant, you must send it back as response from the server) of the file in 
       a new tab (for text-like files, like JSON) (e.g.
       https://jquery.com/download/ the way JQuery provides their
       downloads)

If you choose the second, remember that the file will stay on the server, unless you delete it.

Comment: Yes, I need to save the data to a file automatically. I have an "export" button that once the user clicks it I get the updated data from the table and use the table-to-json plug-in to format the data, which so far I've only managed to log the output to the console, so now I just want to save the updated data back to the same file it was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Post your json back to the server, then have the server expose the file as an attachment accessible via a link, button, etc.